# Shopify apps / oauth access / Get products correctly sorted from a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, shopify-app

`ProductsListing` and `CollectionListing` aren't reachable from the oauth authentification (while building apps), those are reserved for plus-users.

The Smart collections of our store are sorted manually. I could not spot the correct way to retrieve the products of a collection correctly sorted

We're currently using the `shopify_api` gem, but searched a lot, unable to find out.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an endpoint labelled:

```
/admin/smart_collections.json
```

Where you can easily interact with your Smart Collections. For example, if your collection is set to manual sorting, there is a PUT resource you can create to change the order of products. In the Shopify API gem under resources you will find SmartCollection.

To read products from your Smart Collection send the collection_id param to the Product endpoint. If Shopify does not return products in the collection sort order, you're screwed I guess.

Comment: am sorry this is not my point. Sorting products (updating the order) within a collection is okay. Retrieving products as they've been sorted, within a collection, is not available — as of Im aware of.

Comment: This one `/admin/products.json?ids=632910392,921728736` does not even preserve the order of the id sequence passed

Comment: Send the collection ID to the Product endpoint and see if your results are sorted.

Comment: yep had tried also `ShopifyAPI::Product.all(params: {collection_id: xxx})`. Here is the solution https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/shopify-apps-oauth-access-get-products-sorted-manually-from-a-collection-or-wherever-else-503559 Two calls are required to get it correctly sorted; feels a bit awkward not to provide a better access

Comment: A Collect is only relative to a Custom Collection, yet you spoke only of Smart Collections in your questions. So now I am confused. You say the issue is solved but that seems impossible.

Comment: Alex is directly contradicting the "Collect" is just for Custom Collections but hey, whatever.. if it works, it works..

    ShopifyAPI::Collect.where(collection_id: ID)

Comment: Collect works for both; smart and custom. As listings. What's jot working is the order of products, which requires two queries

Comment: I am very confused to have confused an expert; while i haven't said anywhere it was solved. Alex is providing me a way to get the expected result. But again, it feels very weird that one have to make two calls to get a correct ordering for products in a smart collection

Comment: Why two calls? If Collect.where call works for both, that is one call

Comment: What do collect returns ? Joins, sorted. What all other collection/products queries mentionned here return ? Products, unsorted. Get the problem ?

Comment: I have the same problem. My App allows the customer to sort products. I have to therefore restrict them to Custom Collections, as Smart Collections do not allow you to save collects... but I can save collects for custom collections... so I need to be sure the products are delivered in the new sort order...

Comment: I had to hack the gem too, as the products method on a collection only returns 50.. not terribly useful for larger collections.

Comment: Well the update you mentionned do work well and does reflects in the admin ui; but not in the api. I'd expect such company to get to the bottom of such things :/. But as you said; we're might be kinda screwed on this one

Comment: Well.. for sure, you can get the collects for the sort order, and the products, with two (or more calls)... and then use Ruby to sort them manually... so yay...